# I want to replace string with particular format?

Tags: php, string

I have

```
active#100,200#
activea#89,2656#
date 10/2/2014
```

I need output like

```
active
activea
date 10/2/2014
```

I write for this

```
$value2=preg_replace("#","",$value);
$value2=preg_replace("/[0-9,]+/","",$value2);
```

but in this case it removing date digit also I want to remove just #anyno,anyno# value from above.

How can I do this?

solution accepted.

thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all you forgot to wrap regex with delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$value1 = preg_replace('/#.+#/','',$value1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$value2=preg_replace("/#(.*?)#/","",$value);`

Comment: it removing all from $value